# TestNG Reporter org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@7a79be86 failed java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I'm new to TestNG framework, I have written script for an application using TestNG framework. Script working fine but yet I'm getting an error at the end of console. Error attached. 
Please anyone can help me.
Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlgIF.png)

Comment: Can you provide your code portion please?

Comment: [TestNG] Reporter org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@7a79be86 failed
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
 at org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter.getNextConfiguration(JUnitReportReporter.java:220)
 at org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter.generateReport(JUnitReportReporter.java:105)
 at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1175)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1102)
 at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTest

Comment: @user3782636, It appears that you're importing Junit items instead of TestNG. Could you please share the code or just import the correct TestNG   resources

Comment: Please help me to add correct TestNG resource, i'm very new to selenium. Correcting the resources myself with your help would make me to understand the problem well and i could solve those issue in future.

Answer (score 7):

Edit: **Fixed in 6.10**

It is a known issue in the latest release (6.9.13.x) and will be fixed in the next release: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1168

Issue also appears while I'm testing with release - 6.8.

Comment: There is no issue in my script right. Once it fixed in next release can i sort out this issue?

Comment: Yes, it should be. As workaround, you can try using a previous testng version

Comment: Thank you!! I Got Clear.

Comment: JFYI: seems to be fixed in 6.10

Comment: It fails in 6.14.3 too? Should we use 6.10 only?

Comment: Could you open an issue on github if you still have the problem with the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I already had that issue with testng beta version 7. After that I updated version to 6.14.3 and now everything is fine.