# TESTNG ConcurrentModificationException while running with @Test invocation count greater than 1

Tags: unit-testing, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-eclipse

I am experiencing the following issue while running my tests. However, it only happens when I am using @DataProvider with a @Test that has invocation count greater than 1. I am not sure if the following link below is the same issue, because if I read correctly this issue has already been fixed in higher versions of the Eclipse TESTNG plugin 6.9.13.X (using this 6.9.14.201610261028).

[TestNG Reporter org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@7a79be86 failed java.util.ConcurrentModificationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213267/testng-reporter-org-testng-reporters-junitreportreporter7a79be86-failed-java-ut)

**Here is a simple code that is encountering the same problem:**

```
@Test(dataProvider = "data", timeOut = 6000, threadPoolSize = 10, invocationCount = 5)
    public final void x(String a,
            String b, String c, String d,
            String e, String f, String g){

        System.out.println("D"
                + " - "
                + java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getId()
                + " - "
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));

    }
```

**Here is a sample output:**

> Thread - 1274 - 2016-10-28 08:47:23.889 PASSED: x("00336293615",
>   "02/24/2016", "03/10/2016", "3", "0", "3", "11.57") 
>   Thread - 1275 - 2016-10-28 08:47:23.897 
>   Thread - 1273 - 2016-10-28 08:47:23.898
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException     at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.testng.reporters.TextReporter.logResults(TextReporter.java:80)    at
>   org.testng.reporters.TextReporter.onFinish(TextReporter.java:32)  at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.fireEvent(TestRunner.java:1239)     at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:1030)  at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:636)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

**Sometimes it will also throw the following exceprions:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at java.io.Writer.(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.JsonMessageSender.sendMessage(JsonMessageSender.java:37)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.MessageHub.sendMessage(MessageHub.java:43)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.RemoteTestListener1.onTestSuccess(RemoteTestListener1.java:88)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1695)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1675)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:700)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)    at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:75)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:14)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Trying to send a message on a shutdown sender     at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.JsonMessageSender.sendMessage(JsonMessageSender.java:31)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.MessageHub.sendMessage(MessageHub.java:43)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.RemoteTestListener1.onTestStart(RemoteTestListener1.java:49)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1700)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1675)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:619)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)    at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:75)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:14)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Please tell me if you guys need more information.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I created 2 issues for the problem: https://github.com/testng-team/testng-remote/issues/38 and https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1221

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: As workaround, you can use a previous testng version like 6.9.10